# Let $W\subset R^4$ be the subspace of vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ satisfying $2x_1 - x_3 + x_4$ = 0

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W\subset R^4$ be the subspace of vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ satisfying $2x_1 - x_3 + x_4$ = 0.

Find an orthogonal basis for W

Comment: I'd start by finding a basis for $W$, then applying Gram-Schmidt to this basis.

Comment: Change the question showing what you have tried and where you found issues so that we can help you, people won't do your homework for you here.

Answer (score 1):

A basis is $\{(1,0,2,0),(0,0,1,1),(0,1,0,0)\}$

I found this by knowing that the existence of an equation which must hold decreases the dimension of the subspace by 1 (from 4 to 3). Then I extracted 2 bases out of the equation by setting $x_3 = 1$ and $x_4 = 0$ and solving for $x_1$. I then repeated this process for $x_3 = 1$ and $x_1 = 0$ and solving for $x_1$. Then, realizing that $x_2$ can be anything, I made (0,1,0,0) another basis vector.

This set is linearly independent. If vectors 1 and 2 are linearly independent, then the set of all three is (by inspection), and solving the system $\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha2x_2 = 0$ $$\alpha_1(1,0,2,0) + \alpha_2(0,0,1,2) = (0,0,0,0)\\ \alpha_1 = 0, 0=0, 2\alpha_1 = \alpha_1, \alpha_2 =0$$ Since $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$, the set is linearly independent.

This set of vectors spans the described subspace. I can't think of a good way to actually prove this, but if you derive any additional vector from the equation, and append it to the set, such as $(1,0,0,-2)$, then the set becomes dependent, as $(1,0,2,0)-2(0,0,1,1)-(1,0,0,-2) = (0,0,0,0)$.

Now that you have a basis, you should easily be able to make an orthogonal basis.